# comparing the values of two Integers

Tags: java, arrays, comparison, integer

I want to compare the values of two arrays of type Integer. I get the wrong answer when I compare their exact values, and the correct answer when I compare them with Arrays.equals:

```
    Integer a[]=new Integer[2];
    Integer b[]=new Integer[2];
    a[0]=138;
    a[1]=0;
    b[0]=138;
    b[1]=0;
    boolean c;
    c=a[0]==b[0];//c is false
    c=Integer.valueOf(a[0])==Integer.valueOf(b[0]);//c is false
    c=Arrays.equals(a, b);//c is true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`intValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue%28%29), not `Integer.valueOf` (though it's easy to see how you could get them confused!):

```
c = a[0].intValue() == b[0].intValue();
```

Java has primitive types (`int`, `byte`, `double`, etc.) and also reference types (objects) corresponding to them for those situations where you need an object. Your code doing `a[0] = 138;` is auto-boxing the primitive value 138 inside an `Integer` instance.

`intValue` returns the primitive `int` contained by an `Integer` instance. `Integer.valueOf` is used for getting an `Integer` instance (from an `int` or a `String` — in your case, it'll use `valueOf(int)` by auto-un-boxing your `Integer` reference).

You can also do this:

```
c = (int)a[0] == (int)b[0];
```

...which will trigger auto-unboxing.

More about boxing (including auto-boxing and unboxing) in [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7).

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer.a and b were values of a Hash, and it was the reason that they were Integer.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing implicit type conversion (auto-boxing) in your code.

The line:

```
a[0]=138;
```

actually translates to:

```
a[0] = Integer.valueOf(138);
```

creating an instance of Integer. The catch is that this method caches Integers from -128 to 127([How large is the Integer cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052216/how-large-is-the-integer-cache)) and creates new instance for values higher then 127 , hence == comparison returns false.

```
/**
 * Returns an {@code Integer} instance representing the specified
 * {@code int} value.  If a new {@code Integer} instance is not
 * required, this method should generally be used in preference to
 * the constructor {@link #Integer(int)}, as this method is likely
 * to yield significantly better space and time performance by
 * caching frequently requested values.
 *
 * This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127,
 * inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.
 *
 * @param  i an {@code int} value.
 * @return an {@code Integer} instance representing {@code i}.
 * @since  1.5
 */
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

Note that actual type of a[0] is an Integer, so you can write

```
c=a[0].equals(b[0]);
```

which will return true.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the arrays, I don't think the inner values are going to get automatically unboxed for you.  this might work if you had an `int[]` instead of an `Integer[]`