# How large is the Integer cache?

Tags: java, integer, boxing

Class `Integer` has cache, which caches the `Integer` values. So if I use method `valueOf` or inboxing the new value will not be instantiated, but get from the cache.

I know that the default cache size is `127` but can be extended due to VM settings. My question is: how large is the default value of cache size in these settings and can I manipulate this value? Is this value depended on which VM I use (32 or 64 bits)?

I'm now on tuning of a legacy code, and probably will need the conversion from int to Integer.

Clarification: Following code I've found in Java source

```
private static class IntegerCache {
    static final int low = -128;
    static final int high;
    static final Integer cache[];

    static {
        // high value may be configured by property
        int h = 127;
        String integerCacheHighPropValue =
            sun.misc.VM.getSavedProperty("java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high");
        if (integerCacheHighPropValue != null) {
            int i = parseInt(integerCacheHighPropValue);
            i = Math.max(i, 127);
            // Maximum array size is Integer.MAX_VALUE
            h = Math.min(i, Integer.MAX_VALUE - (-low));
        }
        high = h;

        cache = new Integer[(high - low) + 1];
        int j = low;
        for(int k = 0; k < cache.length; k++)
            cache[k] = new Integer(j++);
    }

    private IntegerCache() {}
}

public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    assert IntegerCache.high >= 127;
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

So I think the cache is configurable.

Comment: It is in the Java source code. The VM settings have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Isnt it from -128 to +127? I don't think it can be changed, unless the vm allows configuration (which Ive never seen).

Comment: You can set a different limit with the system property `java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high`. It's all there in the source code.

Comment: How can I set it? System.setProperty or something else?

Comment: In older java versions it was not configurable.  In Java 7 it is.

Comment: @Don, super, thats great to know - thx!

Comment: It's strange that `high` is configurable but `low` is hardcoded.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Internal Java implementation and could not be configured, the range is **from -128 to 127**. You can check `Javadocs` or simply take a look at sources:

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
         final int offset = 128;
         if (i >= -128 && i <= 127) { // must cache
             return IntegerCache.cache[i + offset];
         }
         return new Integer(i);
}
```

**UPD.** I was **wrong** (thx to Marco Topolnik). All of the above is related to older Java implementations. For **Java 7** implementation could be achieved with system property:

```
-Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=<size>
```

or JVM setting:

```
-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<size>
```

**UPD. 2** `java.math.BigInteger` has hardcoded cache for values **-16 <= x <= 16**. From sources:

```
    private final static int MAX_CONSTANT = 16;
    private static BigInteger posConst[] = new BigInteger[MAX_CONSTANT+1];
    private static BigInteger negConst[] = new BigInteger[MAX_CONSTANT+1];
    static {
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_CONSTANT; i++) {
        int[] magnitude = new int[1];
        magnitude[0] = i;
        posConst[i] = new BigInteger(magnitude,  1);
        negConst[i] = new BigInteger(magnitude, -1);
    }
    }

    public static BigInteger valueOf(long val) {
        // If -MAX_CONSTANT < val < MAX_CONSTANT, return stashed constant
        if (val == 0)
            return ZERO;
        if (val > 0 && val <= MAX_CONSTANT)
            return posConst[(int) val];
        else if (val < 0 && val >= -MAX_CONSTANT)
            return negConst[(int) -val];
        return new BigInteger(val);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a similar cache for [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)?

Answer (score 4):

For Java 7, I wasn’t able to find in Oracle’s java documentation is a description of exactly what would change when -XX:+AggressiveOpts is used. So I ran a process to determine the effect aggressiveopts has on jvm settings on one of our app servers in the lab that had java version:
{quote}
java version "1.7.0_15"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_15-b03)
{quote}

The process is to run java with aggressiveopts **disabled**:
java -d64 -server -XX:-AggressiveOpts -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version

The process is to run java with aggressiveopts **enabled**:
java -d64 -server -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version

This process produced these differences:

bool AggressiveOpts    false   -->  true     {product}

**intx AutoBoxCacheMax   128     -->  20000**    {C2 product}

intx BiasedLockingStartupDelay 4000 --> 500  {product}

bool EliminateAutoBox false    -->  true     {C2 diagnostic}

Answer (score 1):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html):

> public static Integer valueOf(int i)
>
> Returns an Integer instance representing the specified int value. If a
>   new Integer instance is not required, this method should generally be
>   used in preference to the constructor Integer(int), as this method is
>   likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by
>   caching frequently requested values. This method will always cache
>   **values in the range -128 to 127**, inclusive, and may cache other values
>   outside of this range.

But you really shouldn't rely on this or try to change anything about this. This is an implementation detail of the JVM which should not influence your implementation.

Comment: While I think it'd be a bad idea to rely on this cache, the reason for me to avoid it would be my desire to have my code clean. I disagree with your comment about "implementation detail"; this isn't an implementation detail. If it's in the Javadoc, then it's binding: you can safely assume (if you're a fan of ugly code) that `-128` to `127` will be cached.