# Integer comparison, 10 and 128

Tags: java, integer

I found an interesting fact, but I don't know how it happened.

```
Integer x = 10;
Integer y = 10;
System.out.print(x==y);    // true
```

```
Integer x = 128;
Integer y = 128;
System.out.print(x==y);    // false
```

Comment: You need to use `.equals()` here.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772763/why-equals-method-when-we-have-operator); `==` and `.equals()` behave differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Integer` comparison using `==` works only for numbers between -128 and 127.

Because `Integer` is an `Object`, use `equals` that will work for all values.

Comment: Actually it works for all Integers where you want to test Object identity. When you create a Integer object with valueOf() or by boxing you get cached singletons for Integers in the range -128…127 (but this is configurable) https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052272