# Why is that a concatenation using "+" operator of a Java reference variable and a literal does not result in String interning?

Tags: java, string

Consider following snippet.

CASE #1

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "abc";
        String str2 = "ab";

        str2 = str2 + "c";

        System.out.println("str1 :" + str1+ ", str2 :" + str2);

        System.out.println(str1 == str2);
    }
}
```

The result is

```
 sh-4.3$ java -Xmx128M -Xms16M HelloWorld                                                                                                                                        
 str1 :abc, str2 :abc                                                                                                                                                            
 false
```

Here, the result of `str1 == str2` comes out to be false. However, if you use "+" operator to concatenate two literals. It gives you the address of the string literal "abc" from string constant pool. Consider following snippet

CASE #2

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "abc";
        //String str2 = "ab";

        str2 = "ab" + "c";

        System.out.println("str1 :" + str1 + ", str2 :" + str2);

        System.out.println(str1 == str2);
    }
}
```

The result is

```
  sh-4.3$ java -Xmx128M -Xms16M HelloWorld                                                                                                                                        
  str1 :abc, str2 :abc                                                                                                                                                            
  true
```

Can someone please explain why string interning is done in CASE #2 and not in CASE #1? Why do we get 'str1==str2' as false in CASE #1 and true in CASE #2?

Comment: Examine the byte code with `javap -v`; you'll see why.

Comment: There is a cost to interning. You probably don't want it for non-constant strings by default (and in the first case, there is a part that looks variable at first glance -- i.e. without potentially involved static code analysis).

Answer (score 3):

Because the [JLS #3.10.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) specifies compile-time interning of string literals or constant string expressions, and doesn't specify any interning in the case of non-constant string expressions.

Also specified in [JLS #15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice because of the Final, the compiler considers this a constant expression and interns it in this case as well.

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String []args) {
    String str1 = "abc";
    final String str2 = "ab";

    String str3 = str2 + "c";

    System.out.println("str1 :" +str1+", str3 :"+str3);

    System.out.println(str1 == str3);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just interned (still concatenated at runtime) or already concatenated by the compiler (bytecode already contains "abc")?

Comment: @Thilo By the compiler, at complete time. 'The compiler ... interns it'.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial factor isn't that it's a string literal, it's that it's a constant expression. This is defined in [JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), which lists all of the ways you can have a constant expression. That list includes "literals of type `String`" and concatenations of two String constants*, but not of non-`final` variables, even if those variables happen to be set and never changed.

JLS 15.28 is also what specifies that "Constant expressions of type String are always 'interned'", so if something is *not* a constant expression -- for instance, if it includes non-final variables -- then it won't be interned.

---

<sub>* This is expressed slightly awkwardly, but basically 15.28 says that an expression is constant if it only consists of a bunch of things, and one of those things is the additive operator `+`, which for Strings performs concatenation -- there's not actually a separate "concatenationi operator."</sub>

Comment: The crucial factor is not the constant expression but the rule in [JLS #3.10.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) that says what to do with it.

Comment: @EJP if you do `final String s1 = "foo" ; String s2 = s1 + "bar"; s2 == "foobar"` then you'll get `true`, even though s2 consisted of a non-literal.

Comment: I agree. I haven't stated otherwise.

Comment: @EJP And JLS 15.28 also says what to do with it. In fact, JLS 3.10.5's mention of string literals explicitly says that it's a special case of 15.28.

Comment: I agree with the first part. Again, I haven't stated otherwise. But there is nothing in 3.10.5 about special cases for interning.

Comment: @EJP Ok, then I guess the disagreement is on whether the crucial aspect is the general rule or its specialization :)

Comment: Now that you've provided the rule about interning, there is little disagreement here, apart from this non-existent business about specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Several of the existing answers here already cover, in a strict sense, why the interning doesn't happen: *it isn't required by the JLS*.

The JLS specicies both that interning *must* happen in the `"literal" + "literal"` case (per [15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1), and also that non-constant expressions must be *newly created* (also in 15.18.1). The relevant section on newly created objects seems to leave open the possibility of the compiler or runtime interning the non-literal case as well (quotation marks added):

```
Execution of a string concatenation operator (§15.18.1) that is not part
of a constant expression (§15.28) "sometimes" creates a new String object
to represent the result. String concatenation operators may also create
temporary wrapper objects for a value of a primitive type.
```

Here, I believe the *"sometimes" creates* part refers to the fact that the compiler (or runtime) can optmize away a series of concatentation operations within a single expression, such as `foo + 1 + anotherFoo + bar()` to *newly create* only a single string for the final result - but it does not allow a compiler or runtime to intern the final result.

One practical reason it would not be a good idea to intern all strings is that interning is a relatively expensive, global operation. Interned strings must be recorded, checked for uniqueness, and all that must be safe across threads which may involve a lock or some faster but still slow lock-free logic. In fact, in large applications, `String.intern()` can be a significant contention point if the size of the default intern table is not increased (it seems locking occurs per-bucket in the table).

Once the requirement was written in this way, it's essentially impossible for future specifications to loosen it, since existing code may easy depend on objects being *newly created*: the distinction is readily evident not only via operator `==` but also when locking an object, using identity hash codes, etc.

For a counterpoint, consider the behavior of autoboxed integers, as well as the related static methods such as [`Integer.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29):

```
This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127,
inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.
```

The caching mentioned here is essentially equivalent to interning. In this case, the JLS left open the possibility of interning integers outside the range -128 to 127 - i.e., left it up to the implementation. Indeed, this makes the use of `valueOf` less predicable for the developer, but gives more flexibility to the implementation, and this flexibility was in fact used in JDK 7 to [increase the size of the cached integer range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15052216/149138) - and even to make it configurable by the end user who launches the JVM.