# Is it safe to compare two `Integer` values with `==` in Java?

Tags: java

I have this Java code:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Integer x = 5;
         Integer y = 5;
         System.out.println(x == y);
    }
}
```

Is it guaranteed to print `true` on the console? I mean, is it comparing the two boxed integers by value (which is what I need to do) or by reference identity?

Also, will it be any different if I cast them to unboxed integers like this

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Integer x = 5;
         Integer y = 5;
         System.out.println((int) x == (int) y);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is comparing them by reference identity. Integers in the range `-128` to `127` are cached, which is why Integer instances are sometimes the same reference. But you are better off using `equals`.

Comment: It will work but is highly discouraged. Compare literals with `==`. Compare objects with `equals()`

Comment: the thing is that if I write `(int) x == (int) y` the IDE (I'm using intellijIdea) tells me that the cast is unnnecessary

Comment: @khelwood They will be the same. Caching is documented behavior.

Comment: If needed you can do `x.intValue() == y.intValue()`, but it is better to just use `x.equals(y)`

Comment: @shmosel Yes, they will be the same in this specific case. In general two integers of the same value _might_ be the same but are not necessarily.

Comment: @Andreas what if one of them is `null` and the other is `0`?

Comment: @oggioniw If either might be null, you need to null-check it (or use [`Objects.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))). Using `.equals` or `.intValue()` or `(int)` *all* risk raising a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @khelwood +1 for suggesting usage of [Objects.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it's not the right way to compare the `Integer` objects. You should use `Integer.equals()` or `Integer.compareTo()` method.

By default JVM will cache the `Integer` values from [-128, 127] range (see [`java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052272/1602555)) but other values won't be cached:

```
Integer x = 5000;
Integer y = 5000;
System.out.println(x == y); // false
```

Unboxing to `int` or calling `Integer.intValue()` will create an `int` primitive that can be safely compared with `==` operator. However unboxing a `null` will result in `NullPointerException`.

Comment: what if I cast them to unboxed integers like this `(int) x == (int) y`?

Comment: For full answer, mention use of `Objects.equals` as [commented by khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167297/is-it-safe-to-compare-two-integer-values-with-in-java?noredirect=1#comment97074301_55167297) as solution to null issue.

Comment: Also cache range is configurable since Java7

Answer (score 0):

No it is not the right way to compare to object directly.You can convert to int value and compare.

Java implementation

Where value is of type int.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Integer) {
            return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
        }
        return false;
    }
```